# Cache POJOs from RMI

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, caching

I am implementing cache in standalone application for POJOs that are received via RMI. The problem is next. Lets say we have two persons with the same company.

```
class Company {
  Long id;
  List<User> users;
}

class User {
  Long id;
  Company company;
}
// + getters & setters

// CLIENT:
// get persons from server via RMI
User user1 = server.getEntity(User.class, 1);
User user2 = server.getEntity(User.class, 2);

assertEquals("Companies not the same instance!" , user1.getCompany(),user2.getCompany());
```

Problem: After deserialization in RMI we get two different instances of company entity. If company on user changes, the change is not seen from the other user, so we can't cache such objects. There must be only one instance of every object.

Idea: Every time entity is loaded, check if it is already in cache. If it is, copy all values to cached instance, so we preserve all references. Do the same recursively for loaded entity's relations.
This way we always have only one entity instance in cache and preserve all its references. Is there a more effective way to do it? Does any library already solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you use a cache on the server-side, RMI will still serialize the object so on the client-side you still end up with a new object instance.

There is nothing wrong with this approach, since that's how [detached entities](http://vladmihalcea.com/preventing-lost-updates-in-long-conversations/) are supposed to work anyway. Using an [optimistic locking approach should prevent data consistency issues](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-database-locking-and-the-lost-update-phenomena/).

Comment: Before concurrent transactions problem and the need for optimistic locking, I have to solve inconsistent data in the client standalone application. Im quite surprised more people aren't facing the same problem and there is no library that would solve this yet.